# PHP getting variable or reading from appdata

Tags: php

I have a small problem that I need help with. folder in poker on the server in a file called "index2.php" shall obtain a username from a variable in the "index.php" located in the folder one level higher than the "index2.php" is in.

the problem here is that inside "index.php" then I get this: "`$ _SESSION ['mafiaqloggetinnbruker']`"

and it can not retrieve it since it is defined in the "index.php".

This I need for it to load a user from a page a user is online, and use it in another file.

else if there are any ways to do this, how can I make that case a "hidden" text line in a file in appdata defined by the user, which it can use to download to use in index2.php?

if this was really messy writing, please say so :)

some code:
$usr = $_SESSION['mafiaqloggetinnbruker'];

in my index.php file:

```
$query  =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE  `brukernavn`='$brukernavn'  AND `passord`='$passord'")  or  die('Error: '.mysql_error());
        $fetcha =   mysql_fetch_object($query);
                    $_SESSION['mafiaqloggetinnbruker'] = $fetcha->brukernavn;
```

I need the username it uses on index.php to work in index2.php . not using the acual code, but just getting the name from the session it uses in index.php

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in index2?

Comment: "This was really messy writing." :-)

Comment: yes i have. im trying to get the session mafia...(as said above) to work in index2.php

Comment: Do you also have `session_start()` in `index.php`?

Comment: yes i have.

and dosent i need some sort of require('../index.php'); or something? anyway, if i do that the acual index.php from the folder above is showing :|

Answer (score 0):

in every file you use the session, start it with `session_start()`

Also I hope the space after `$ _SESSION` is not in your actual code...

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
// start the session
session_start();

// saving a value in a session variable
$_SESSION['mafiaqloggetinnbruker'] = 'the_value';
```

**index2.php**

```
// start the session
session_start();

// getting the value from the session
$myLocalVar = $_SESSION['mafiaqloggetinnbruker'];
```

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE `brukernavn`='$brukernavn' AND `passord`='$passord'") or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
  $fetcha = mysql_fetch_object($query);

 $_SESSION['mafiaqloggetinnbruker'] = $fetcha->brukernavn;


remember they are in two different folders.